# Registering a sdp service with bluez on Fedora 20

Tags: linux, bluetooth, fedora, bluez

I'm trying to build a bluetooh service through bluez on Linux. According to that tutorial [http://people.csail.mit.edu/albert/bluez-intro/x604.html], it is necessary to connect to the local SDP server in order to register the service. But "sdp_connect( BDADDR_ANY, BDADDR_LOCAL, SDP_RETRY_IF_BUSY)" is returning NULL here and all the services related to bluetooth are running without any problem on my Fedora, apparently. Whenever I try to get information about the SDP local server through the command "sdptool browse local", I get the following message: "Failed to connect to SDP server on FF:FF:FF:00:00:00: Connection refused". Some users say it is necessary to get sdpd running in order to use sdp_connect and here there is no package with binary called sdpd, but I think sdpd is now part of bluetoothd on Fedora, so a sdp server was supposed to be running when sdp_connect tried to connect. Why sdp_connect is not working?

Comment: Do you have bluetooth device connected ? For me, it looks like device is unable to register with bluez or bluetoothd is not running

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to start bluetoothd with --compat flag. I don't know if this is the "Fedora way" of doing it, but I edited /usr/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service and included the flag in the ExecStart option.

```
ExecStart=/usr/libexec/bluetooth/bluetoothd --compat
```

Then

```
$ systemctl daemon-reload
$ systemctl restart bluetooth.service
```

Comment: This workaround works also on ubuntu 16.04. Need to edit `/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service` and do `sudo systemctl daemon-reload && sudo service bluetooth restart`

Comment: Please, don't use "--compat" option to enable compatible mode -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/56238884/323182

Answer (score 0):

Running the daemon in compat mode worked for me - but I needed to sudo my test program.

It was very kind of bitfox to slap our wrists. Perhaps. for the benefit of us lesser mortals, he would like to upload a few pointers on how to advertise our RFCOMM services with bluez5.