# Bluetooth SDP - where is sdpd?

Tags: android, bluetooth, debian, sdp

**Where is the Bluetooth Service Discovery Protocol (SDP) Daemon?**

I'm trying to register a bluetooth service on Debian V8.0 using bluez. I use example code at https://people.csail.mit.edu/albert/bluez-intro/. Everything goes well until I try

```
sdp_connect( BDADDR_ANY, BDADDR_LOCAL, 0 );
```

which fails. After some digging, I find that the sdp daemon (sdpd) (to which it needs to connect) is not running and in fact does not even exist on my system.

**What I Tried:**

1. I have installed (apt-get) every bluetooth or bluez package that seemed remotely relevant but still no sdpd.
2. I tried to connect using the address of my Android phone (using the same code). That worked fine but, of course, is of no use.
3. Did an exhaustive Google search on the problem but found no clear answers. A lot of talk about hcid, pand, etc. but no clear answers about how these are relevant.

**My Goal:**

I am trying to register my service on my Debian system, so that I can connect to it from another bluetooth device (in particular, my Android). The service runs just fine, it just can't be found without SDP registration.

I'd be satified to connect to it directly, using it's (known) channel number, but Android can only connect via a registered service UUID (i.e., using `BluetoothDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid)`), but I see no API to connect to a *channel*.

Interestingly, I *can* connect to a service on the Android by *channel number*, but not the other way around.  Me thinks maybe sdpd is obsolete - all references to it are several years old.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[SOLVED] Apparently, sdpd is long gone. It's function has been subsumed by bluetoothd. To make it work, use the --compat flag, e.g.

```
bluetoothd --compat
```

This should be added to "/etc/init.d/bluetooth".
With this, I can successfully connect and register my service.

I found a hint to this in a blog posting. Why the release notes or anything else on the planet never announced this, I have no idea.

Answer (score 5):

From the official [bluez project site](http://www.bluez.org/bluez-5-api-introduction-and-porting-guide/):

> The BlueZ 5 D-Bus API contains significant changes compared to BlueZ
>   4. The bulk of the changes are due to the following features in BlueZ 5:
>
> - Transformation to use standard D-Bus Properties and ObjectManager interfaces (available in the D-Bus specification document)
> - Introduction of interface versions (e.g. org.bluez.Adapter1). When new versions are introduced we’ll try to keep supporting at least the
>     two latest versions simultaneously.
> - The simplification or removal of per-profile interfaces and the addition of a general org.bluez.Device1.Connect method to connect
>     profiles.
> - The removal of the org.bluez.Service interface (used for registering SDP records and authorization) and the introduction of a new
>     org.bluez.Profile1 interface
> - Dynamic device object creation during device discovery
> - Introduction of an AgentManager1 interface
> - Base path moved to “/org/bluez”. This shouldn’t make much difference though as the main entry point to any interaction through D-Bus is the
>     ObjectManager.GetManagedObjects call.

In short, starting from Bluez5 you cannot use *sdp_connect()* like functions. **You must use D-Bus**. In the page linked above, you can also find the following:

> BlueZ 5 introduces a new generic D-Bus interface for implementing
>   external profiles. The profile (residing in a separate process)
>   implements a org.bluez.Profile1 interface and registers an object
>   implementing it through a new ProfileManager1 interface on the BlueZ
>   side. In the RegisterProfile method (on the ProfileManager1 interface)
>   the profile needs to at least provide the UUID for the profile to be
>   registered. BlueZ has internally a table of defaults for common
>   profiles so no other information is necessarily needed. However, if
>   the profile desires to it can provide information such as the full SDP
>   record (XML encoded), desired security level, enable/disable
>   authorization, version, features, role, name, etc.

... and a lot of precious informations.

Please, don't use the compatibile mode (I mean the "--compat" option). You should use it only for testing and development:

```
commit 83b21cc152186f12f8bc76b7aec3107e220d5219    
Author: Marcel Holtmann <marcel@holtmann.org>   
Date:   Mon Dec 17 14:02:59 2012 +0100

    core: Hide /var/run/sdp support behind command line option

    By default /var/run/sdp support has been disabled from now on. It is not
    the preferred way of handling SDP records. For testing and development
    purposes it can be switched back on via --compat command line option.
```

Last but not least, here is a collection of useful links that could help the new users/developers working with Bluez5:

- The [Profile API](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/profile-api.txt)
- [Bluez APIs doc](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc)
- [Bluez examples in python](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/test)
- Another interesting [sample code](https://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-bluetooth/msg67331.html)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will help you, but it might be worth a try. I also had some problems with Debian 8 Bluetooth; I solved my problems by enabling Debian backports and downloading the newest backport version of `blueman`. To do that, first uninstall your current bluetooth packages (main ones, such as `bluez`), and then add this lines (or similar) to your `/etc/apt/sources.list`

```
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main contrib non-free
```

Then run a `apt-get update` and install the backport version. I suggest using the following code to make sure that the configuration file is updated to the latest version:

```
apt-get update && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -qy -o DPkg::options::="--force-confnew" -t jessie-backports install blueman
```

Reboot your computer and see if it is working now. Note: enabling the backports on Debian will not install all backport versions of software available (nor would you want that). Only when you specifically request the backport version (like we did above) it will be installed. All other packages will be maintained as they are (stable). When updating, your backport packages will update with the latest backport version, and your stable packages will update with the latest stable version.

**Edit:** This answer was edited to add some enhancements and information.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I had a minor (I think) problem with apt-get update with the new sources. Got what appeared to be a warning "The following signatures could not  be verified because the public key is not available:  ... ". I think it was just a warning though.  I tried apt-cache search for anything like "jessie" "backports", "bluez" etc. but didn't see anything relevant that was not already installed. I am also confused by the "DEBIAN_FRONTEND=..." line. Where does that go?

Comment: I would suggest you to uninstall your bluetooth packages first before installing the new ones (I added that to my answer). Installing the backport version of `blueman` via apt-get should get you all the (backport or not) dependencies you need -- see: https://packages.debian.org/jessie-backports/blueman . Not sure about your "...public key is not available: ... " warning, it should not happen. After you add the backports to your `/etc/apt/sources.list` you should run apt-get update (I added that to my answer). The `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` bit is optional, to make it run unassisted.

Comment: Please also note that I believe the capability of connecting via Bluetooth and mount your external device as a volume and copy and paste files/folders to and from the device/computer has been "phased out" on Debian 8. Now they are forcing you to use the "push" system (or whatever is called), so you can select one file/folder on the computer/device and "push" it to the other. On Debian 8 I could never have 2 windows showing the files of the device and the computer and copying and pasting between the the windows (sadly). Even the push function only worked with the backport packages.

Comment: [Solved] See answer below.