# How to check that SDP service record was registered correctly in C++/Linux

Tags: c++, c, bluez, sdp

I am trying to register my bluetooth SDP service in C++ linux as shown here:  [Example 4-9. Describing a service](https://people.csail.mit.edu/albert/bluez-intro/x604.html)

Where or how can I check exactly that the service is registered? I've tried viewing all services while running `bluetoothctl` or `sdptool browse` commands but service with my UUID is not shown there.

I've also tried changing the service group (not sure how it is called) in `sdp_uuid16_create(&rootUuid, PUBLIC_BROWSE_GROUP)` call to, for example, `sdp_uuid16_create(&rootUuid, SERIAL_PORT_SVCLASS_ID)` and searching with `sdptool search SP` as it is shown here [Bluetooth Profiles](http://trac.gateworks.com/wiki/wireless/bluetooth) but it does not take any effect.

When I run discovering services program (first paragraph on the site) on my other PC, it finds the service pretty fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The document you linked to is refering to a version of BlueZ that most systems don't run anymore.

Many of the tools it refers to (such as `hciattach`, `hciconfig`, `hcitool`, `hcidump`, `rfcomm`, `sdptool`, `ciptool`, and `gatttool`) were deprecated by the BlueZ project in 2017.

There is also the following SO question talking about the changes that have happened to BlueZ: [Bluetooth SDP - where is sdpd?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41290114/bluetooth-sdp-where-is-sdpd)

Libraries such as https://github.com/nettlep/gobbledegook are examples of using the new D-Bus API in C.

The BlueZ documentation for the APIs are available at:
https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc

Comment: Thank you for your advice! Actually, I haven't noticed that example I was using is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to check all local SDP records by typing `sdptool browse local`. In this case I can see my record the lowest in list:

```
Service Name: Service Name
Service Description: Service Description
Service Provider: Service Provider
Service RecHandle: 0x10010
Service Class ID List:
  UUID 128: aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa
  "Serial Port" (0x1101)
Protocol Descriptor List:
  "L2CAP" (0x0100)
  "RFCOMM" (0x0003)
    Channel: 1
Profile Descriptor List:
  "Serial Port" (0x1101)
    Version: 0x0100
```